# Zip file download through API results in corrupted file - DRF + Axios

Tags: python, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, zip

I am trying to send a zip file through an API in DRF and download it using axios in VueJS.

The python code

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=['POST'], url_path='download-as-group')
def download_group(self, request, pk=None):
  # For the sake of permissions
  resource = self.get_object()
  file, filename = resource.downloadZip()
  FilePointer = open(file,"rb").read()
  response = HttpResponse(FilePointer,content_type='application/zip')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'#+filename
  response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file)
  if settings.CLIENT_ENV != "ONPREM":
      pathlib.Path(file).unlink()
  return response
```

The JS Code

```js
axios
  .post(
      API_url,
      {
          responseType: 'blob',
      }
  )
  .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]), { type: 'application/zip' });
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", "test.zip"); //or any other extension
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
  })
```

The file successfully downloads, but windows can not open the zip file.

[image]

[image]